# How to use Node.js in SharePoint

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

May be it's old.
can anyone help me to navigate 
How can i use **Nodejs** with **sharepoint 2010/2013.**
How Apps built can be hosted and powered with Node.JS

Thanks a Ton

Comment: Are you planning to get SharePoint data using JS or only to host node apps in SharePoint?

Comment: Host of Node.JS Apps as priority.